my code doesnt run on python-telegram-bot version 20.6. Python 3.13.0
I am not a programmer, but I need help editing the code. As I understood from some sources, the problem is in the version of python-telegram-bot. The code is written on version 20.6 and it is different from the new version. Please help me figure it out.
    import logging
    from telegram import Update
    from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, MessageHandler, filters, ContextTypes


    logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO
    )

    # Paste your bot token
    TOKEN = '123456789:nbvcswertyuikjnjuytfvcd'  

    # Your channel ID and list of groups to forward
    CHANNEL_ID = '-1003456543243' # Replace with your channel
    GROUP_IDS = ['-39314832857', '-2384173258']  # Replace with your group IDs

    # Function for forwarding messages
    async def forward_message(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
        if update.channel_post:
            for group_id in GROUP_IDS:
                try:
                    await context.bot.forward_message(
                        chat_id=group_id,
                        from_chat_id=update.channel_post.chat.id,
                        message_id=update.channel_post.message_id
                    )
                    logging.info(f"Сообщение переслано в группу: {group_id}")
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error(f"Ошибка пересылки сообщения в {group_id}: {e}")

    #The main function to run the bot
    async def main():
        application = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).build()

        # Setting up a filter to receive messages from a channel
        channel_filter = filters.Chat(CHANNEL_ID)
        application.add_handler(MessageHandler(channel_filter, forward_message))

        logging.info("Бот запущен и работает. Ожидание сообщений...")
        await application.run_polling()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import asyncio
        asyncio.run(main())


My code doesn't run is a vague problem description. What specific problem are you having with the code you've posted? Do you get an error message? If so, please [edit] your post to include the complete, exact error message. Are you getting different behavior than you expect? If so, what do you expect, and what is happening instead? You can't just dump a bunch of code here and say It doesn't work. Fix it. and expect us to do so. You have a responsibility to clearly describe the problem you're having, and you've not done so yet. Until we know what's wrong, we can't help fix it.
